# Definition of simple function

Tags: measure-theory

Firstly I'm sorry for this dumb question, anyway I can't grasp the real meaning of simple function, the starting point to construct the Lebesgue integral, and I hope someone will help me. 
Basically, I don't understand why the simple function should be written as a finite linear combination of characteristic functions. 
$$s(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n a_n \chi_{A_n}(x)$$
Why should we express this idea by taking a sum? I'm not an advanced student in maths, I think my problem is just understanding the meaning of this summation, so I really need a very simple answer. 
Moreover, I know that such a representation is not unique, anyway how could we make it unique? Many thanks.

Comment: It may help if you come up with a few basic examples over the real line and try to draw what the functions look like. For example, $\chi_{[0,1]}$ then maybe $\chi_{[0,1]}+2\chi_{[2,3]}$, and so on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's simply superposition of each of the individual terms. Outside each set $A_k$, the term vanishes; inside this set, the term has value $a_k$. The terms therefore don't "interfere" with each other. (I'm assuming the $A_k$ are pairwise disjoint.) you obtain the simple function by layering together these even "simpler" pieces.

**More:** Note that you can write

$$s(x) = \begin{cases}
a_1, & \textrm{ if }x\in A_1 \\
a_2, & \textrm{ if }x\in A_2 \\\
\cdots & \\
a_n, & \textrm{ if }x\in A_n \\
0, & \textrm{ otherwise }\\
\end{cases}$$

But since the $A_k$ are presumably pairwise disjoint (if not, union them up and replace them by a single such set), we have that any $x$ will belong to *at most* one of them. Another way to say that is that $\chi_{A_k}(x)$ will be nonzero (since it takes the value $1$) for *at most* one value of $k$. Since all of the others are zero, you can add them all up (you're mostly adding up a bunch of $0$ terms with at most one nonzero term); of course, the $k$ will depend on $x$ if it exists:

$$s(x) = a_1\underbrace{\chi_{A_1}(x)}_0 + a_2\underbrace{\chi_{A_k}(x)}_0 + \cdots + a_k\underbrace{\chi_{A_k}(x)}_1 + \cdots + a_n\underbrace{\chi_{A_n}(x)}_0$$
$$\require{cancel}= \cancel{a_1\cdot 0} + \cancel{a_2\cdot 0} + \cdots + a_k\cdot 1 + \cdots + \cancel{a_n\cdot 0}$$
$$=a_k$$

If $x$ isn't in any of the $A_k$, then all of the terms are zero and $s(x)=0$, uninteresting, but still equal to that sum.

Comment: Thanks, I'm thinking about what you're saying, and this sounds clear. However, how can I make this representation unique? I've written in my notes that the real number a1 should be greater than a2 and so on... But this is not clear at all.

Comment: Sure it is. The range of a simple function is finite -- it only assumes the values $a_1,\ldots,a_n$. For simplicity, think of simple functions as step functions to start with. Then think about what happens if you allow more complicated sets on which the function is constant

Comment: I'm so sorry, I didn't get your last explanation.